# Jenkinsfile cifsPublisher not copying right files using wildcards

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins scripted pipeline I'm trying to copy files to a remote Windows Share using [cifsPublisher](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)

As documented [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-Examples) I should use `myPrj/deploy/**/*` as `sourceFiles` pattern but files I expect to be copied are not.

This is my Jenkinsfile step:

```
stage('Save WAR'){
    //
    sh 'ls -laR ./myPrj/deploy/'
    //
    cifsPublisher(publishers: [[
        configName: 'myConfig',
        transfers: [[cleanRemote: false,
            excludes: '',
            flatten: false,
            makeEmptyDirs: true,
            noDefaultExcludes: false,
            patternSeparator: '',
            remoteDirectory: 'Server',
            remoteDirectorySDF: false,
            removePrefix: '',
            sourceFiles: './myPrj/deploy/**/*' ]],
        usePromotionTimestamp: false,
        useWorkspaceInPromotion: false,
        verbose: true]])        
}
```

This is the verbose output:

```
+ ls -laR ./myPrj/deploy/
./myPrj/deploy/:
totale 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins  41 ago  3 11:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 jenkins jenkins 299 ago  3 11:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins  65 ago  3 11:57 myPrj-01.01.01-201808031155

./myPrj/deploy/myPrj-01.01.01-201808031155:
totale 443392
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins        65 ago  3 11:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins        41 ago  3 11:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 269154173 ago  3 11:57 Dist.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins       168 ago  3 11:55 INFO.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 184870342 ago  3 11:57 myPrj##01.01.01.war
[Pipeline] cifsPublisher
CIFS: Connecting from host [jenkins]
CIFS: Connecting with configuration [myConfig] ...
CIFS: Removing WINS from name resolution
CIFS: Setting response timeout [30.000]
CIFS: Setting socket timeout [35.000]
CIFS: Setting buffer size to: [4.096] Bytes
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE/Jenkins/Server/.com.apple.timemachine.supported]
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE//Jenkins/Server/Jenkinsfile]
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE/Jenkins/Server/build.gradle]
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE/Jenkins/Server/gradlew]
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE/Jenkins/Server/gradlew.bat]
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE/Jenkins/Server/sonar-project.properties]
CIFS: copy [smb://WinServer/SHARE/Jenkins/Server/vstop.png]
CIFS: Disconnecting configuration [myConfig] ...
CIFS: Transferred 7 file(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Files that are copied are from the workspace root directory.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug but i found a workaround using `dir` and setting `patternSeparator` to `/`

```
stage('Save WAR'){
    dir('myPrj/deploy/') {
        cifsPublisher(publishers: [[
            configName: 'myConfig',
            transfers: [[cleanRemote: false,
                excludes: '',
                flatten: false,
                makeEmptyDirs: true,
                noDefaultExcludes: false,
                patternSeparator: '/',
                remoteDirectory: "Server/",
                remoteDirectorySDF: false,
                removePrefix: '',
                sourceFiles: '**/*' ]],
            usePromotionTimestamp: false,
            useWorkspaceInPromotion: false,
            verbose: true]]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but this fix isn't an option for me. I guess you didn't find the underlying issue?

Comment: @unknownSPY take a look here if helps: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52997